# Does terraform module need "dependency lock file"?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-modules

I'm confused about how to manage the "dependency-lock-file" named .terraform.lock.hcl in my module.
In my team terraform repo, there is a lockfile in a module.

I think it is not the position, since there is no reason to command `terraform init` in the module.
So I'm gonna remove it. Do you guys think it is okay?

Comment: Please take a look here first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. But to answer your question, I don't think it should be inside of the module code.

Comment: @MarkoE I've read your links but I can't recognize what you want for me. which point should I have to correct?

Comment: Well, for one, you are asking for an opinion, which could lead to your questions being closed (not this one though, but for the future reference).

Comment: @MarkoE I understand. thank you for your information. I'll care not to ask opnion or something seems like opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dependency lock file is for an entire configuration (a tree of modules starting at a root module) rather than for individual modules.

Due to how Terraform CLI works the dependency lock file ends up placed in the same directory as the root module -- the directory that you run `terraform init` etc from -- but it isn't technically part of the root module itself, and instead records the provider version selections made for the entire configuration tree.

Therefore a module that is intended only to be called from other modules using a `module` block does not need to have a `.terraform.lock.hcl` file in its directory, and Terraform will ignore any such file if it isn't in the root module directory where you run `terraform init`.

There is some subtlety here, though: a module that's normally used only as a shared module via a `module` block might still nonetheless be used directly when you are developing it. This will be particularly true in the forthcoming Terraform v1.6 which adds a `terraform test` command for automated integration testing of shared modules. In that case you would run `terraform init` in the module's directory only to perform development tasks, and the `.terraform.lock.hcl` file created will record selections that apply only to your development environment for that module. They'll still be ignored when the module is called from another module using a `module` block.